# I'm using KingFisher library to load gif into a collection view and it causes memory issues and crashes. What can I do to lower memory usage?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, gif

This is the collection view memory usage and sometimes it increases drastically. I'm fetching lots of animated gifs from Firebase and setting them with postImageView.kf.setImage(with: url) [image]

Comment: I'm fetching gif from Firebase and setting them with postImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

Comment: And are these images bigger than necessary for the given size of `postImageView`? If so, use that `DownsamplingImageProcessor`...

Comment: Yes, they are bigger. So this causes the memory issue?

Comment: I tried the DownsamplingImageProcessor but the gifs stop animating. They are shown as images.

Comment: Using the original, high resolution assets will consume a lot more memory than it would if you resized it using the KingFisher processor. And, remember, your image assets are compressed, but they’re uncompressed when used in the image view, using four bytes per pixel of the underlying image, regardless of the image view frame. Resizing the images mitigates this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I’m not surprised that any animations were lost. But how was memory? Did it solve that problem? (This helps confirm whether this was the issue.) Bottom line, a collection view with high res animated gifs will always consume a lot of memory. You might want to look for solutions that resize animated gifs. (I personally don’t know of any, but someone has presumably tackled this problem...)

Comment: The memory dropped to about 50MB. So yes, the problem appears to be the images.